# How to fix "expected a single document in the stream, but found more" error when running yamllint command

Tags: java, spring, yaml

I need to check yaml file in my local machine by running command

```
yamllint -d "{extends: relaxed, rules: {line-length: {max: 800}}}" application.yml
```

However it always return error as below:

```
✖ YAML Lint failed for /Users/Peter/IdeaProjects/configuration/application.yml
✖ expected a single document in the stream, but found more
```

My computer is MACOS 10.12.6 
The content of that file is not a problem, because my friend run the same command and it checked successfully without any problem with file's content.

Comment: Are you at the same package version number as your friend? Without knowledge of the actual file content, the OS your friend is using, and the version of yamllint and pyyaml compared to your friend's versions, it is difficult to do anything but guess. Also note that `yamllint` relies on the  PyYAML package [without any version number](https://github.com/adrienverge/yamllint/blob/master/setup.py#L54) which has bumped two major version numbers recently.